# Using Geb and the Edge WebDriver I get failed to create driver from callback

Tags: selenium, gradle, microsoft-edge, geb

In my current automation project I am attempting to automate my testing based on various browsers using Gradle and Geb.  I've been able to get all browsers working with the exception of Microsoft Edge.  Currently I am seeing:

> geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from
>   callback

I've verified that I am downloading the MicrosoftWebDriver.exe to the expected directory in my project but I am not sure if I am missing something in my driver setup:

```
driver = {
        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions()
        options.pageLoadStrategy("eager")
        edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver()
        return edgeDriver
    }
```

I am fairly new to Geb and Gradle as a whole so it is entirely possible I am missing something.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my issue was due to having just upgraded my local machine to Windows 10 and the Microsoft Web Driver preview build requires the Fall 2015 update which is unavailable to me for 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware You need more than just the exe to use the MS Webdriver. The machine that's executing the Webdriver code will need to have one of the following MSI's installed:

- For Windows 10 Build 10240, install this version of Microsoft [WebDriver](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=716880).
- For Windows 10 Fall 2015 Update, install Microsoft WebDriver [Fall 2015 Update](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=716879).
- For the latest preview build from the Windows Insider Program, install this version of [Microsoft WebDriver](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=716882).

I think the MSI changes some switches in Edge to enable it to be controlled by Web driver.